# Weird SSL common name mismatch

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Today I came across a weird case of cn mismatch. I have two domains:

kpmg.talentsource.rs and 
www.kpmg.talentsource.rs

both have prod.q.ssl.global.fastly.net as their CNAME
they have the same A records and certificates.

Nevertheless:

https://kpmg.talentsource.rs (OK)

https://www.kpmg.talentsource.rs (CN mismatch)

---

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kpmg.talentsource.rs&s=151.101.65.62
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.kpmg.talentsource.rs&s=151.101.65.62

Note: none of the two has the kpmg.talentsource.rs in neither the the CN nor the SAN

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @TheNewOne I don't own the servers. I am just curious. Regardless of that, I am interested to know why the certificate fails, not why the server returns 500 when connected, which shouldn't require access to the server. e.g. how chrome identifies that the certificate of the first domain is good and the second's is bad?

Comment: Removed the comments because they were misleading. The answer seems right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate has a Subject Alternative Name of `*.talentsource.rs` (among many others unrelated one).

Per X.509/TLS rules, a `*` matches only one level/label, it does not cross the dot so to say. So `*.talentsource.rs` matches an hostname of `kpmg.talentsource.rs` but **NOT** `www.kpmg.talentsource.rs`, hence the browser error.

You need either to add `www.kpmg.talentsource.rs` or `*.kpmg.talentsource.rs` as a SAN (note that it has `talentsource.rs` already in the list too) in this certificate or stop using `www.kpmg.talentsource.rs` at all (a redirection will not solve the problem as you still need the TLS handshake to complete first before getting the HTTP `Location:` header, so you still need appropriate certificate).